# Is it possible to prevent users from viewing some content in files using Active Directory property permissions?

Tags: active-directory, file-permissions

Here's the scenario: I manage an desktop enterprise application for mid-sized companies, and the field layout on some of the application's screens are controlled by XML files (1 XML file controls the field layout for its application screen). The XML file contains an XML tag for each field, and each field has a group of property tags; here's an example of one of the field-level XML tags, along with its properties/sub-tags (the properties/sub-tags are the same for all fields, only the data in each tag will change between fields):

```
<Control>
<ButtonHint></ButtonHint>
<CascadeTable></CascadeTable>
<Column>6C64CB49-0968-4062-B882-20FC730B9656</Column>
<ColumnSize>0</ColumnSize>
<ColumnType>D</ColumnType>
<ControlType>qaDate</ControlType>
<DataField>QDATEREMOVEDTOF</DataField>
<Expression></Expression>
<Height>21</Height>
<IsAllowNull>Y</IsAllowNull>
<IsWorkflowEnabled>N</IsWorkflowEnabled>
<LabelText>Date Removed to Federal Court</LabelText>
<Left>36</Left>
<LookupType></LookupType>
<Picture></Picture>
<QATabOrder>11</QATabOrder>
<Query>MattersQuery</Query>
<ShowRecNo>False</ShowRecNo>
<SubType>qlNeither</SubType>
<Top>202</Top>
<Width>264</Width>
</Control>
```

My goal is to selectively change permissions to the XML file contents, depending on the user (or user group); by doing this, I could hide specific fields from the user interface, and create field-level security.

Is there a way to control whether users can view specific field-level tags (and their contents)? I was thinking that maybe this could be done via Active Directory and setting property permissions on the XML file?

If this isn't possible via Active Directory, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This would only be possible if you modified the application. There is no way to use permissions of any kind to selectively hide parts of an xml file.

Instead, you might be able to use multiple copies of the file and a symbolic link to control which version of the file is access by the program.

Comment: Thanks, Ashigore, that sounds like it might work--though I'd need to test it. I've never heard of symbolic links; can you point me to a resource on how I could configure that?